# Is it safe to remove gnome-session on a clean Ubuntu 11.10 install?

Tags: nautilus, gnome-session

I want to replace Nautilus with PCManFM on a clean Ubuntu 11.10 install. Removing Nautilus will remove `gnome-session` as well though, and I'm not completely sure about this. Is it safe to remove `gnome-session`?

Comment: Are you installing LXDE/Lubuntu-desktop - or do you just want to use another file-manager on the gnome-desktop.

Comment: I just want another file-manager on the gnome-desktop; it is a clean Ubuntu install, not a Lubuntu install. And I want to remove Nautilus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `nautilus` will remove the following packages.

```
 gnome-session nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-share ubuntu-desktop
```

The removal of gnome-session will remove Unity and Unity 2D.  On a clean install you will not have any sessions to log into!

You could install `gnome-shell` from the software-center first before removing nautilus.

After removing nautilus you will be left with two sessions to log into - gnome-classic and gnome-classic (no effects).

Since you have removed nautilus - you will not be able to right-click and drop files and folders onto the desktop.

You could add to `pcmanfm --desktop` to your startup applications to get the capability back.